# I want to get the page URL where my external links has been authored using Query builder in AEM

Tags: sql, aem, query-builder, external-links

I am working on external links, in which some of the Links are invalid. Here i need to get the page path where the Invalid URL's are linked. Also the external links are authored in some components across the website and i cant able to access the referrer in external links( as i don't have permissions to enable) trying to get the page path using Query builder.

I am working on external links, in which some of the Links are invalid. Here i need to get the page path where the Invalid URL's are linked. Also the external links are authored in some components across the website and i cant able to access the referrer in external links( as i don't have permissions to enable)so trying to get the page path using Query builder.